# How to add an XML sub-element to a simple data type in C#

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-serialization

I'm trying to serialize a simple data type into XML, but in a particular way to satisfy an existing API. (assume that the desired XML must be formed in this way)

Here is the desired XML:

```
<foo>
<value>derp</value>
</foo>
```

I would ideally like to represent this in a class as just

```
String foo;
```

The only two options I know of are

1. Simple serialization, which of course just leads to

```
    <foo>derp</foo>
```

1. creating a Foo class, which creates the desired XML, but forces the user to type

```
    myFoo.Value = "derp";
```

instead of the preferable

```
foo = "derp";
```

Is there any way to have the simple string in the class, but represent it with the `<value>` sub-element?

Comment: Why do you want to serialize it in this way?

Comment: to satisfy an existing API (edited original question)

Comment: Can you not implement [`IXmlSerializable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable.aspx) on the class that contains `foo`, to take complete control of the serialization?

Answer (score 5):

Use this implementation:

```
[XmlRoot("foo")]
public class Foo
{
    [XmlElement("value")]
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public static implicit operator Foo(string s)
    {
        return new Foo { Value = s };
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
private static void Main()
{
    Foo foo = "abc";

    var ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
    ns.Add(string.Empty, string.Empty);

    var serialzier = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Foo));

    using (var writer = new StringWriter())
    {
        serialzier.Serialize(writer, foo, ns);

        Console.WriteLine(writer.ToString());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<foo>
  <value>abc</value>
</foo>
```